# Scanning for beacons and getting location periodically in the foreground

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-location, ibeacon-android, foreground-service

I am using the beacon library to scan for beacons with a foreground service and a persistent notification. I have tested this on both Android 9.0 and 7.0, and the app works as expected, and sends the beacons scanned to a server every 30 seconds. Now, I am trying to add location scanning to the app, so that it retrieves location updates every 30 seconds. I am using the Google Play API, and set up a location request with an interval of 30 secs. Then, I created a FusedLocationProvider client in my application class, so I gave it my app's (not activity's) context. Then, I gave my request and the following callback to the client:

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback()
  {
     @Override
     public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult)
     {
        if ( locationResult != null )
        {
           Log.d(TAG, "location acquired: " + locationResult.getLastLocation());
           beaconContainer.setLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }
     }
  };
```

The beaconContainer object holds a list of beacons and the latest location (and a timestap of when the latest location was acquired using LocalTime.now()), and sends these to the server every 30 seconds. At first, the app seems to work and the location timestamp is within 30 seconds of when the request to the server was sent. However, after some time has passed (and the screen has been off for some time), it seems that the onLocationResult method in the callback is not being called and the location is not being updated. For example, the server request was made at 12:34 but the location was updated at 10:21. Note that the beacon scanning is still being correctly performed as expected.

I was wondering if this is because the phone that I tested this on was stationary, or if it is because I did not use a service for location updating. To me, it seems to be the former because my app has a foreground service (ble scanner) and a persistent notification, so according to the docs, it is in the foreground and it should not be subject to background limitations. If it is the latter, how can I fuse the beacon library's foreground service with my location scanning so that they both run as expected.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of battery historian, showing how BLE is regularly and consistently being used while GPS is used for intermittent periods.
[image: Battery historian]

Comment: did you try with location update services?

Comment: @BlackBlind you mean putting my code in a service? No, I haven't done that. I thought since my app already has a foreground service, it is a part of the foreground and so the application will not be killed and I can run the location code in the my application class. I am sure the app is not killed because it keeps sending beacon updates to my server.

Comment: It looks like you also want to send location updates to server.??

Comment: @BlackBlind Yes, I send both beacons and locations to the server. Every time the beaconContainer.setLocation() method is called, it saves a timestamp of when the method was called. That is how I know location stops being reported after some time.

Comment: finally you are facing a problem to update a location in server??

Comment: @BlackBlind The problem I am having is the onLocationResult method not being called every 30 seconds. For example, take a look at the screenshot I added. Note how GPS is active (meaning that onLocationResult is being called) for around an hour before it becomes deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `FusedLocationProviderClient` indicates that on Android 8+, if the app is not in the foreground, you will only get updates a "few times each hour".  See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current).  This is likely because the implementation inside Google Play Services uses the JobScheduler on Android 8+ to get around background service limits, and jobs are limited to running every 15 minutes +/- 5 minutes in the background.  Since Google Play Services APIs are closed source and proprietary, it is difficult to say more about its internal implementation, but it is unlikely that it takes into account that your app has a foreground service.  (The Android Beacon Library, by contrast, is explicitly designed to behave differently when configured with a Foreground Service so you get more frequent updates.)

It's unclear how the `FusedLocationProviderClient` works differently in the background on Android 7.  It may not work differently at all, and may follow the pattern described above in the background simply if your app *targets* SDK 26 or higher.  You'd have to test to make sure -- effectively reverse engineering Google Play Services.  Even if you do figure it out, the behavior might change in the next Google Play Services version, and you'll never know about it unless you reverse-engineer it again.  This is the peril of using closed-source SDKs.

An alternative would be to instead use the open-source location APIs provided by Android.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
          this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
try {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400l, (float) 1000.0, this); //You can also use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER
}
catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Can't get location -- permission denied");
}
```

Of course, you'll want to adjust the accuracy and update interval to suit your needs and conserve battery.  And you will certainly find dropouts in callbacks when your phone enters Doze mode.  But you should be able to use the above in your Application class as you describe in your question without the annoyingly opaque behaviors added by Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to the same documentation you linked, since I have a foreground service, my app should not be considered as a background app right? And I see this behavior in Android 7.0, not just 8.0. Also, as soon as I turn on the phone's screen, it goes back to getting location as expected, so it cannot be because of the background limitations. I am guessing it is because the OS goes into doze, but then how come the beacon scanning continues regularly and consistently.

Comment: Also, does using LocationManager have any adverse effects as opposed to Google Play APIs? Google keeps mentioning that the Google Play APIs are better to use and use less battery and are more accurate.

Comment: Just because the Android operating system considers your app to be in the foreground when enforcing background limits, doesn't mean that Google Play Services will make the same evaluation or alter its behavior.  Understand that Google Play Services is not the operating system.  It is actually a third party app just like your app, and subject to the same background limits. Since Google Play Services does not have a foreground service, it cannot keep running to give you constant updates.   Google Play Services gets broadcast callbacks on screen on events, giving it 10 min of running then.

Comment: "Google keeps mentioning that the Google Play APIs are better to use and use less battery and are more accurate" -- in terms of battery saving this is partly true, but the side effect is that you lose control over behavior -- and you have seen the consequences!   If you want control over behavior, you need to implement battery saving yourself using the open source APIs.